# Keeping multiple directives up-to-date when a shared controllers object changes

Tags: angularjs

I have three directives that all utilize the one controller. A user can go in and edit their name which calls a service to update their details on the backend. The data coming back should then be used to populate the other directives that make use of it in the promises resolve.

A problem I was having was that when viewing one of the directives I'd have to reload the page in order to see the changes populate. My solution was to use $broadcast on the $rootScope and have the directives that needed it listen but this seems like overkill and I don't want to come to rely on this as a performance hit would eventually occur:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('flowlens')
    .directive('flUserCard', flUserCard);

    function flUserCard() {

        var directive = {
           restrict: 'E',
           controller: FlUserController,
           controllerAs: 'vm',
           scope: {},
           bindToController: {
              user: '=',
              userId: '@',
              size: '@'
           },
           templateUrl: '/templates/fl-users/fl-user-card.html',
           link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
              if(scope.vm.size == "small"){
                scope.vm.cardClasses = "col-xs-12 col-lg-4";
                scope.vm.lineClasses = "col-xs-12";
                scope.vm.hrClasses    = "";
              } else {
                scope.vm.cardClasses  = "col-xs-12";
                scope.vm.lineClasses  = "col-xs-12 col-lg-4";
                scope.vm.hrClasses    = "hidden-lg-up";
              }
           }
        };
        return directive;
   }

  angular
    .module('flowlens')
    .directive('flUserShow', flUserShow);
  function flUserShow() {

    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: FlUserController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        user: '=',
        userId: '@',
      },
      templateUrl: '/templates/fl-users/fl-user-show.html',
      link: link
    };

    function link(scope, ele, attrs, vm) {
      scope.$on('name change', function(evt,data) {
        vm.user = data.user;
      });
    }

    return directive;
  }

  angular
    .module('flowlens')
    .directive('flUserEdit', flUserEdit);
   function flUserEdit() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: FlUserController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        user: '=',
        userId: '@',
      },
      templateUrl: '/templates/fl-users/fl-user-edit.html'
    };

    return directive;
   }

  FlUserController.$inject = ['FlUsersService', '$state',   '$rootScope'];

  function FlUserController(FlUsersService, $state, $rootScope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.update = update;

    activate();

    function activate(){
       if( !vm.user ) {
             FlUsersService.get({id: vm.userId}, function(result){
             vm.user = result.contact;
          }, function(result){
             console.log(result);
          });
       }
    }

    function update(){
      FlUsersService.update({id: vm.userId, contact: vm.user},     function success(result){
         angular.merge(vm.user, result.user);
         $rootScope.$broadcast('name change',{user: vm.user});
         $state.go('users.show', {userId: vm.user.id});
      }, function failure(result){});
    }
  }
 })();
```

So my question is really this - is there a more efficient way of doing the same thing to ensure that all directives are updated when the controller updates the user object?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is how I'm passing them into the directive - double bound:

```
var directive = {
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: FlUserController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  scope: {},
  bindToController: {
    user: '=',
    userId: '@',
    size: '@'
  },
  templateUrl: '/templates/fl-users/fl-user-card.html',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
       if(scope.vm.size == "small"){
         scope.vm.cardClasses = "col-xs-12 col-lg-4";
         scope.vm.lineClasses = "col-xs-12";
         scope.vm.hrClasses    = "";
       } else {
         scope.vm.cardClasses  = "col-xs-12";
         scope.vm.lineClasses  = "col-xs-12 col-lg-4";
         scope.vm.hrClasses    = "hidden-lg-up";
       }
     }
  };
 return directive;
```

All the directives has this same signature minus the link part

Comment: Could you reproduce in a plunkr or fiddle? Technically since you seem to be using isolated scope with two-way binding `user: '='` it should actually update automatically without needing the broadcast way. Have you tried initializing vm.user before calling activate? i.e. `vm.user = null; activate();`

Comment: Exactly - that's what I would expect to happen hence why I'm asking this question. I tried initializing the vm.user variable before but it crashed the app...

Comment: The crash you referring to is a really good indication that there are other bugs that need to be sorted out first, and are probably related to the two-way binding issues you are seeing. Try to initialize it to an empty object: `vm.user = {};`

Comment: Can you show the template? Just curious on how these 3 directives are receiving the `user` object. Pretty sure 2 way binding should be sufficient here.

Comment: @KashyapMukkamala Sure - see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to introduce service for this "global" objects.  Than you can require this service as dependency and put into scope (if needed). You can use `value` as simple object storage (`value` is simplest `Provider`).

This way you abstract source of modification - you don't care who modified object, you just track changes.

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.value('user', {});
app.directive('first', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>First directive, name={{ctrl.user.name}}</div>',
    controller: CommonCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  }
});
app.directive('second', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Second directive, name={{ctrl.user.name}}</div>',
    controller: CommonCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  }
});

function CommonCtrl($scope, $timeout, user) {
  if (!user.loaded) {
    $timeout(function() {
      if (!user.loaded) {
        user.name = 'Bob';
        user.loaded = true;
      }
    }, Math.random() * 500);
  }
  this.user = user;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">Loading...
  <first></first>
  <second></second>
</div>
```

I assumed you have "global" object. In case if you have "scopes" where you can have several objects, but shared within some hierarchy, you can introduce some "object holder" directive and require it in all directives that can use it.

Note: you can change properties of object, but not object itself. You can use `angular.extend` to put properties from backend object to stored object, or use single property of injected object (e.g. `user.value = valueFromBackend`)